# Angular material display content being clipped

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am currently developing an angular JS / Web application. And currently experiencing an issue with some of the content being clipped in the **md-content** element.

For example i have a **body** tag that has the style: **overflow: hidden** and a child **md-content** tag that has **overflow: auto**. Although the scrollbar appears i am not able to scroll to the end of the page

```
<md-content style='margin-left: 30px;margin-top: 10px' class="_md" layout="column">

     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIO </h3>
     <h3> AAAAAABECEDARIOSSSSS </h3>
</md-content>
```

As can be seen below, the content is clipped and not everything is being displayed.

[image]

Please check that the last tag information:

```
<h3> AAAAAABECEDARIOSSSSS </h3>
```

Is not being displayed

Comment: Maybe you can wrap your <h3> within a <div layout="column">

Comment: Hi Jean, i have wrapped the element in a <div layout="column"> and i am still experiencing the same type of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
<div flex layout="row">
<md-content flex>

   <!-- Put all your titles or whatever here --> 

</md-content>
</div>
```

With of course your style and class attributes in md-content, just add the flex attributes in it and put it in the div

Comment: Thank you for your answer, will be testing it soon.